# how to put sliver widgets inside a stack?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I have a page that has list of data. on top of that list, I have a banner, normally I just use stack to make the banner on the top of the list

but now I use custom scroll view and sliver widgets. so the structure is like this

```
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
            title: .....
        ),
        _MainLayout(),
      ],
    );
  }


class _MainLayout extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Stack( // <--- problem when I put stack in here
      children: [
        SliverList(),
        // I want to place my Banner in here
      ],
    );
  }
  
  
}
```

but as you can see, I haven't even put the banner yet, but I have error when I put the stack widget like that. here is the error message

> The following assertion was thrown building _MainLayout: A
> RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a
> child of type RenderStack.
>
> RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they
> coordinate with their children during layout and paint. For example, a
> RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a RenderSliver
> does not understand the RenderBox layout protocol.
>
> The RenderViewport that expected a RenderSliver child was created by:
> Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#f7350] ← Semantics ← Listener ←
> _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#6effe] ←
> Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#a6a1f] ←
> Scrollable ← PrimaryScrollController ← CustomScrollView ← ⋯
>
> The RenderStack that did not match the expected child type was created
> by: Stack ← _MainLayout ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#f7350] ←
> Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
> RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#6effe] ←
> Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#a6a1f] ←
> Scrollable ← ⋯

so how to put sliver widgets inside a stack?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools here you can find a description about SliverStack, did you check that?

Comment: @stacktrace2234 yup thats exactly what I need.

Comment: Can you add an image that you like to archive? We change switch between widgets to archive same result. 1st error because out customScrollView providing infinite height. And our stack use parent size. That's why you can have errors on 1st place.  2nd  you can't put Slivers inside stack you have to use ListView/column satisfying widget requirements.